# Convex function with non-symmetric Hessian

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, hessian-matrix

Let $U$ be an open convex subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and $f:U\to\mathbb R$ a convex function on it.

- It is a well-known fact that if the second partial derivatives exist everywhere on $U$ and are all continuous (*i.e.,* if $f\in\mathcal C^2$), then the Hessian of $f$ is symmetric, that is, $\partial^2 f/(\partial x_i\partial x_j)=\partial^2 f/(\partial x_j\partial x_i)$ for any $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. (Actually, $f$ needn't even be convex for this result.)
- In fact, [Alexandroff's theorem](http://people.math.sc.edu/howard/Notes/alex.pdf) states that the Hessian exists and is symmetric almost everywhere with respect to the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure, without any additional assumptions beyond convexity.

**Question**: It is possible for $f$ to be twice differentiable (and thus have, not necessarily everywhere-continuous, second-order partial derivatives) everywhere on $U$ but a Hessian that is *not* symmetric at *some* $x\in U$?

---

*Update*: [Dudley (1977)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mscand.dk%2Farticle%2Fdownload%2F11710%2F9726&ei=EhT9VJuuHIWWgwTv5oPYBQ&usg=AFQjCNFw0nfChTrNB9aqNxz-nFCLHcHj2Q&sig2=-LK4IuHO1quHk9Xud2uy9g) gives an example of a convex function with an existent and asymmetric Hessian at the origin. This counterexample doesn't settle my question, however, because Dudley's function doesn't have a second-order (Fréchet) derivative (*i.e.*, not twice differentiable) at the origin (even though the second-order *partial* derivatives exist). I would like to see a convex function with *both* an existent second-order Fréchet derivative *and* with asymmetric Hessian at some point (which necessarily implies that some of the second-order partial derivatives are discontinuous at that point).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out that twice-differentiability implies that the Hessian is symmetric even without convexity and with no reference to whether the second-order partial derivatives are continuous! The proof below is based on Theorem 8.12.2 in the book *Foundations of Modern Analysis* by Dieudonné (1969, p. 180).

**Claim:** Let $U\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ be an open set and $f:U\to\mathbb R$ a function. Suppose that $f$ is (Fréchet) differentiable on $U$ and that it is twice (Fréchet) differentiable at $\mathbf x_0\in U$. Then, the Hessian matrix $\mathbf H(\mathbf x_0)$ at $\mathbf x_0$ is symmetric.

*Proof:* Let $\mathbf D:U\to\mathbb R^n$ denote the gradient function of $f$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Since $\mathbf D$ is Fréchet differentiable at $\mathbf x_0$ by assumption, it follows that there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $\|\mathbf v\|<4\delta$ implies that
$$\left\|\mathbf D(\mathbf x_0+\mathbf v)-\mathbf D(\mathbf x_0)-\mathbf H(\mathbf x_0)\cdot\mathbf v\right\|\leq\varepsilon\|\mathbf v\|.$$
There is no loss of generality in taking $\delta$ to be so small that the open ball $B(4\delta,\mathbf x_0)$ is contained in the open set $U$.

For any $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, let $\mathbf e_i$ and $\mathbf e_j$ be the corresponding standard basis vectors of unit length. Let $\mathbf s\equiv\delta\mathbf e_i$ and $\mathbf t\equiv\delta\mathbf e_j$. It is clear that $\mathbf x_0+\xi\mathbf s+\mathbf t$ and $\mathbf x_0+\xi\mathbf s$ are both in $U$ whenever $\xi\in[0,1]$; this is because $\|\xi\mathbf s+\mathbf t\|<4\delta$ and $\|\xi\mathbf s\|<4\delta$. Define the following function $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$:
$$g(\xi)\equiv f(\mathbf x_0+\xi\mathbf s+\mathbf t)-f(\mathbf x_0+\xi\mathbf s)\quad\forall\xi\in[0,1].$$

Clearly, $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$. Lagrange's mean-value theorem, in turn, implies that there exists some $\xi\in(0,1)$ such that
$$g(1)-g(0)=g'(\xi)=\mathbf s\cdot\left[\mathbf D(\mathbf x_0+\xi\mathbf s+\mathbf t)-\mathbf D(\mathbf x_0+\xi\mathbf s)\right],$$
using the chain rule.

Next, one can derive the following chain of inequalities (the first one uses the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality):
\begin{align*}
&\left|g(1)-g(0)-\mathbf s\cdot\mathbf H(\mathbf x_0)\cdot\mathbf t\right|\leq\underbrace{\|\mathbf s\|}_{=\delta}\left\|[\mathbf D(\mathbf x_0+\xi\mathbf s+\mathbf t)-\mathbf D(\mathbf x_0)]-[\mathbf D(\mathbf x_0+\xi\mathbf s)-\mathbf D(\mathbf x_0)]-\mathbf H(\mathbf x_0)\cdot\mathbf t\right\|\\
=&\,\delta\left\|[\mathbf D(\mathbf x_0+\xi\mathbf s+\mathbf t)-\mathbf D(\mathbf x_0)-\mathbf H(\mathbf x_0)\cdot(\xi\mathbf s+\mathbf t)]-[\mathbf D(\mathbf x_0+\xi\mathbf s)-\mathbf D(\mathbf x_0)-\mathbf H(\mathbf x_0)\cdot(\xi\mathbf s)]\right\|\\
\leq&\,\delta\varepsilon\left(\|\xi\mathbf s+\mathbf t\|+\|\xi\mathbf s\|\right)<8\delta^2\varepsilon.
\end{align*}
That is, one has that
$$|f(\mathbf x_0+\mathbf s+\mathbf t)-f(\mathbf x_0+\mathbf s)-f(\mathbf x_0+\mathbf t)+f(\mathbf x_0)-\delta^2\mathbf e_i\cdot\mathbf H(\mathbf x_0)\cdot\mathbf e_j|<8\delta^2\varepsilon,$$
and, by a completely analogous and symmetric reasoning in which $\mathbf s$ and $\mathbf t$ are interchanged,
$$|f(\mathbf x_0+\mathbf s+\mathbf t)-f(\mathbf x_0+\mathbf s)-f(\mathbf x_0+\mathbf t)+f(\mathbf x_0)-\delta^2\mathbf e_j\cdot\mathbf H(\mathbf x_0)\cdot\mathbf e_i|<8\delta^2\varepsilon.$$
Given that $\mathbf e_i\cdot\mathbf H(\mathbf x_0)\cdot\mathbf e_j=h_{ij}(\mathbf x_0)\equiv\partial^2 f/(\partial x_i\partial x_j)(\mathbf x_0)$, the preceding two inequalities imply that
$$\left|h_{ij}(\mathbf x_0)-h_{ji}(\mathbf x_0)\right|<16\varepsilon.$$
Taking $\varepsilon$ to be arbitrarily small, one sees that $h_{ij}(\mathbf x_0)=h_{ji}(\mathbf x_0)$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Thanks for this excellent exposition of Dieudonne's theorem. This is quite a slick proof. I didn't understand the proof in Dieudonne's real analysis book at first glance: this answer made everything quite clear. +1.

Comment: Great answer. FYI Theorem 12.12 in Mathematical Analysis by Apostol gives a result that (I think) is slightly stronger. The upshot is that Frechet differentiability of the first order partials is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clear answer! May I ask a silly question as to why one would need Schwarz's Theorem then?

Comment: @oliver My understanding (correct me if I’m wrong) is that Schwarz’s theorem is not nested: its premise requires (i) only that the second-order partial derivatives exist (without the original function necessarily being twice Fréchet differentiable), a weaker condition; but (ii) also that the second-order partial derivatives be continuous, a stronger condition. Schwarz’s theorem is more relevant because its premises are more naturally satisfied. Dieudonné’s theorem covers the somewhat pathological cases, which are more interesting from a theoretical rather than a practical point of view.