# What does it mean for $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ to be twice differentiable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Given some function $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, it is twice differentiable if $g'(x)$ and $g''(x)$ both exist. But what about something like $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. Now I have partials to worry about. What is the definition of being twice differentiable in this case?

Comment: For a precise definition of higher order differentiability, see [A question about derivatives between Euclidean spaces: how should we construct it and interpret its definition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3696211/568204), and regarding the currently accepted answer’s latest edit, a proof (of a very slightly modified statement) can be found here: [Does Frechet differentiability of the first order partials imply twice Frechet differentiability?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3966167/568204)

Comment: @peek-a-boo: That means my answer, after modification is correct? Sadly the answer was accepted before the call to action, so I couldn't delete it and correct it. So, I had to do it on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is similar, only now with partial derivatives. To be $f:{\bf R}^2\to {\bf R}$ twice $\color{red}{\text{[edit: continuously]}}$ differentiable, $\color{red}{\text{[edit: it is necessary and sufficient]}}$ that all second-order partial derivatives exist $\color{red}{\text{[edit: and to be continuous]}}$. That is, $f_{xx},f_{yy},f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ they have to exist $\color{red}{\text{[edit: and to be continuous]}}$.

NB: Notice that more generally $f$ is twice differentiable iff $f$ is differentiable and each partial derivatives $f_{x_j}$ is differentiable. Then, the proposition given above it a result from here.

Comment: This requires proof though. You need to be more careful. If $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$ and assuming differentiability, then  $f'$ is a linear operator $f':\mathbb{R}^n\to L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ so $f''$ becomes a map $f'':\mathbb{R}^n\to L(\mathbb{R}^n, L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)).$ Relating these ideas to the corresponding partial derivatives is not hard, but it is not trivial, either.

Comment: This is false. Existence of partial derivatives does not imply differentiability.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff It seems that when I wrote, I forgot to write the important continuity hypothesis. I think that is now correct.

Comment: Indeed, it should works. Since $f_{x_i,x_j}$ there exists and they are continuous, then they are differentiables. Therefore, $f$ is twice differentiable.

Comment: I believe the edited version is now too restrictive – it is now equivalent to $f$ beeing twice **continuously** differentiable. But the OP only asked about differentiability.

Comment: First line: “To be $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$ twice **continuously** differentiable **it is necessary and sufficient that** all second-order partial derivatives exist **and are continuous**. The first instance of ‘continuous’ is still missing in your answer, and rather than “need”, the more precise statement is ‘necessary and sufficient’. The subsequent edit is fine.

Comment: Thanks, I was just trying to highlight the differentiability conclusion. I will add that part. @peek-a-boo